# Find replace entire string line of variable text using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Working on a batch script that will modify package.json file.

Basically, I need to replace the `"test"` portion of every json file.

This is a sample snippet:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "any text can go here"
  },
```

What I want to do is replace the entire "test" line with:

```
"test": "jest --coverage"
```

I have only come up with a script that replaces a string (without spaces):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%a in (temp.txt) do (
    SET s=%%a
    SET s=!s:test=newText!
    echo !s!>>yourtempfilename.txt
)
pause
```

Can anyone help me modify this so that:
- it can accommodate a string with spaces
- it can replace the entire line with `"test"` considering `"any text can go here"` value is always different

Please note though that I cannot use any other programs/commands such as sed or fnr.bat or something.

Comment: For editing files, do not choose `cmd.exe` commands, use `powershell.exe` with its `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` functionality instead.

Comment: As Compo already said, batch (cmd.exe) is terrible for manipulating text files. You could use [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) to easily and reliably accomplish your task - `jrepl "test" "replacement text" /l /b /e /f "temp.txt" /o -`

Comment: @dbenham: OP doesn't want to replace `test`, but the unknown string thereafter. (no doubt, `jrepl` can do that too though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Compo already commented, batch isn't the right tool for the job, but when you can't use anything other (like PowerShell):

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "newtext=some other text here"
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" temp.txt') do (
  echo %%b|findstr /rc:"\ *\"test\":\ \".*\"" >nul && (
    for /f "delims=:" %%c in ("%%b") do echo %%c: "%newtext%"
    ) || echo/%%b
))>yourtempfilename.txt 2>nul
```

It keeps formatting and empty lines but has some problems with certain poison characters 
(that's why `2>nul`; the output is ok though)